# Word breaking in python doesn't work

Tags: python, algorithm, dynamic-programming

I have a string with a list of words. I want to get all the keywords in the list that exists in the string. But it doesn't work with more than 1 keyword

```
ks = ['Voices', 'Home']

def find_tag(long_string, size, result):
    for idx, s in enumerate(range(0, size + 1)):
        prefix = long_string[0:idx + 1]
        if prefix in ks:
            if idx + 1 == size:
                result += prefix
                print(result)
            find_tag(long_string[idx: size - idx], size - idx, result + prefix + ' ')


find_tag('Voices', len('Voices'), '')

text = 'VoicesandHome'
find_tag(text, len(text), '')
```

The sample input would be string like `'IliveinLondonandIusedtogotoNewYork'`

Given dictionary is `['London', 'New York']`

Output would be `London` and `New York`

Comment: Do you mean something like `[word for word in ks if word in text]`?

Comment: Can you add a sample input and expected output to your question?

Comment: My first impression is that the code looks more complicated than needed. Expect output will also help to see what you want.

Comment: Sorry I just added the sample of input and output. This is my interview question. I'm just practicing.

Comment: Recursion is usually not needed. There is usually an easier way to do it. Agree with @biocyberman. Example is the "in" operator

Comment: What if two keywords overlap? i.e. `ks=['foo','oop']` and `text='foop'`?

Comment: So as @TigerhawkT3 suggested you can use `in` operator here! whats wrong with that?

Comment: If you want to replace the space in @TigerhawkT3's answer you could do `[word for word in ks if word.replace(' ','') in text]`

Answer (score 0):

A few comments about your code:

```
for idx, s in enumerate(range(0, size + 1)):
```

does not make much sense, because `enumerate(range(0,k+1))` will yield `(0,0)`, `(1,1)`, ..., `(k,k)`  (why having the same value in `idx` and `s`?

Your code appears to be iterative (uses a `for` loop), but then it uses recursion in a branch.

Usually (for example in this moderately simple example), either you have dead simple recursive code, or a slightly more complex iterative code. Something appears to be wrong in your code.

---

Depending if the keywords can overlap or not, I'd suggest the very simple and pythonic:

```
[word for word in ks if word.replace(' ','') in text]
```

for overlapping keywords, or a recursive method for non-overlapping keywords:

```
def keywords(text):
    if text == '': return []
    for k in ks:
        if text.startswith(k.replace(' ','')):
            return [k]+keywords(text[len(k):])
    return keywords(text[1:])
```

e.g.:

```
>>> text='IliveinLondonandIusedtogotoNewYork'
>>> ks=['London', 'New York']
>>> keywords(text)
['London', 'New York']

>>> text='foop'
>>> ks=['foo','oop']
>>> keywords(text)
['foo']
```

Answer (score 0):

Well this is my shot:

```
ks = ['London', 'New York']
str1 = 'IliveinLondonandIusedtogotoNewYork'
result=[]
for w in ks:
 if (str1.find(w) != -1): result.append(w) 

print(len(result))
print result[1]
# How python ignore that space?
```

Comment: `find()` can return a `0` if the substring is found at the beginning of the searched string, so `if str1.find(w)` will occasionally fail.